# What is the Best Practice to switch between Old and New Email Server to minimize outage?

Tags: email, mail-server, email-client

I have been using self built email servers for years now on Ubuntu Server with Postfix + Dovecot.

Once before, I have decided to build a newer email server, and I called it by a different Fully Qualified Domain Name than the Old Server was called.
Then of course when the moment of switch over came, I had to alter the Resource Records (A, PTR and MX) in my domain (and at my ISP) to make the switch between the two servers.

The way I remember now, it is something like it wasn't really a smooth switchover, even though I have prepared all the involved Resource Records to have 1min TTL set for a while, it just didn't work straight away, without sweating a lot :).

Also nearly every single email within one folder of emails seem to be contained in a single file surrounded by all sorts of hash and checksum looking data, that made me a little frightend to copy emails from the Old Server to the New Server by linux file transfer.
So, at the end I realised, that once I had both servers hooked up to Thunderbird through IMAP, actualy both containing the same account, I could just drag & drop all my folders from the Old Server to the New Server.

How do experineced people change over to a New Email Server?

Answer (score 0):

During my last successful migration project, I used [dovecot replicator](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Replication). It can transparently replicate mailboxes between two servers, no data loss. You can take your time between the following steps, 0 stress:

1. Set up the new server as a replicator.
2. At this point, your old server will still receive all traffic so let the  replication from the old server to your new server run for a while.
3. Force all incomming (LMTP) and IMAP/POP session to the new server. Best use [dovecot director](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Director).
4. At some point, replication will be from the new server to the old server. Only then, you can get rid of the old server or keep it as backup.

**Note**: Replication is not real time but depending on your hardware and network it can be close to it.

Comment: I have never heard of Dovecot Replicator and Director. I'll have a read... Thanks